# How to calculate the frame timestep/deltatime in an MTKView?

Tags: time, metal, timedelta, timestep, mtkview

I want to get the time since the last frame (known as the *timestep* or *deltatime*) in the `draw` method of `MTKView`. I expect to see values of approximately `0.017` assuming 60 frames per second consistently. The value should rise to about `0.03` if unexpected slowdowns are causing the view to render at only 30 frames per second. I tried several ways.

### [`1/view.preferredFramesPerSecond`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtkview/1536027-preferredframespersecond):

This method is undesirable because it assumes that all frames will execute in the preferred time. If there are slowdowns, the timestep will be inaccurate.

### C [`clock()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html) function:

I noticed that the deltatime is off by about a factor of 10 if I attempt to use `clock()` in the `draw` method in an `MTKView`.

**Minimal Reproducible Example:**

Create a new *'Metal'* game template in Xcode. The one that should render a spinning multicolored cube. Then, in the `draw` method for per frame updates, add the line:

```
// Objective-C
printf("%f\n", (double)clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

```
// Swift
print(Double(clock())/Double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC))
```

Build and observe the printed numbers and the console.

The numbers increase at an irregular and slow rate (about 0.1 per second) instead of by a steady 1 per second.

I also tried to store the previous result in a variable then subtract from the current result and divide by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. I see incorrect deltatime values of around `0.001`.

[Apparently this is because `clock()` gets the CPU time used and not the real time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24728931/16217248). The `clock()` function is not suitable for this.

### [`buffer.gpuEndTime-buffer.gpuStartTime`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75850748/16217248):

This approach has similar issues as the `clock()` approach but worse. I see the deltatime drop to as low as about `1.0e-5` (100 **micro**seconds) when no geometry is being rendered. This is several orders of magnitude off.

I also tried `buffer.kernelStartTime` instead of `buffer.gpuStartTime` to no avail.

This approach also requires MacOS 10.15 or newer. This is undesirable as the code should be as backwards compatible as possible.

### Research:

I could find no relevant results about the use of `clock()` together with a Metal game, or about how to get any timestep or deltatime in Metal or an `MTKView`.

---

How to simply get the deltatime of a frame in Metal (e.g., for accurate physics simulation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get the time since the last frame (known as the timestep or
> deltatime) in the draw method of MTKView. I expect to see values of
> approximately 0.017 assuming 60 frames per second consistently. The
> value should rise to about 0.03 if unexpected slowdowns are causing
> the view to render at only 30 frames per second. I tried several ways.

In your class implementation declare two `CFAbsoluteTime` type variables:

```
@implementation Renderer {

    /*.....*/
    CFAbsoluteTime _deltaTime;
    CFAbsoluteTime _currentFrameTime;
}
```

Then update your `MTKView` draw method like so:

```
- (void)drawInMTKView:(MTKView *)view {
    CFAbsoluteTime currentTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    _deltaTime          = currentTime - _currentFrameTime;
    _currentFrameTime   = currentTime;
    NSLog(@"%f", _deltaTime);

    /*.....*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandbuffer/1442997-addcompletedhandler?language=objc):

> You can use the command buffer’s GPUEndTime and GPUStartTime
> properties to calculate how much time the GPU spends running the
> command buffer:

```
__block dispatch_semaphore_t block_sema = _inFlightSemaphore;
[commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer)
 {
    CFTimeInterval start = buffer.GPUStartTime;
    CFTimeInterval end = buffer.GPUEndTime;
    
    CFTimeInterval gpuRuntimeDuration = end - start;
    printf("%f \n", gpuRuntimeDuration);
    
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(block_sema);
 }];
```

---

> Problem: The numbers increase at an irregular and slow rate (about 0.1
> per second) instead of by a steady 1 per second.

Correct implementation:

```
clock_t c = clock();
/* .... */
printf("Time: %g sec.\n", (double)(clock() - (c)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Comment: Will this get the time the GPU took, including or excluding the wait caused by `preferredFramesPerSecond`? I would like to get the timestep per frame, which should be in most cases, `1/60` of a second.

Comment: @user16217248 yes, it will.

Comment: When I use a variable to store the previous clock, and then subtract from the current clock in the draw loop, and then set the previous to the current, I get values that are typically 1/10 the value I would expect. So the problem seems to be with `clock()` itself.

Comment: I still have problems with `buffer.gpuEndTime-buffer.gpuStartTime`. It actually seems to not take into acount the artifical delay; if not much is being rendered, it produces values such as about `1.0e-5` (100 microseconds) instead of about `0.0167` as expected. And it is only available for newer versions of MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the POSIX [`clock_gettime()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock_gettime.3.html) function. POSIX functions are available for MacOS and by extension Metal games.

```
static struct timespec old;
// Init old once
struct timespec new;
if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &new))
    abort();
struct timespec delta = {new.tv_sec-old.tv_sec, new.tv_nsec-old.tv_nsec};
old = new;
```